# Is it possible to do ldap query and exclude certain OU?

Tags: python, ldap, ldap-query, python-ldap

Using python-ldap to search active directory. How do I exclude certain user with a specific `OU`?
Searching within the group 'GON' and want it to return just regular users with `OU=Users` and not `OU=Foo`.

```
filter = "(&(CN=GON)(!(OU=Foo)))"
attr = ["member"]
scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE

result = l.search_s(basdn, scope, filter, attr)
```

Got result:

```
[('CN=GON,OU=App,OU=Groups,DC=com', {'member': [b'CN=user1,OU=Users,DC=com', b'CN=user2me,OU=Foo,DC=com',]}), (None, ['ldap://skogen.com/CN=Sche,CN=Conf,DC=com']), (None, ['ldap://skogen.com/CN=Sche,CN=Conf,DC=com'])]
```

Want result:

```
[('CN=GON,OU=App,OU=Groups,DC=com', {'member': [b'CN=user1,OU=Users,DC=com']}), (None, ['ldap://skogen.com/CN=Sche,CN=Conf,DC=com']), (None, ['ldap://skogen.com/CN=Sche,CN=Conf,DC=com'])]
```

Comment: What is your directory server (OpenLDAP, Active Directory, etc)?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Most likely active directory and I'm using ldap to call it. Is there a way to be sure if it's active directory or openldap? Would it not be possible to exclude OU's with one of those you mentioned?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter. I just realized you want to filter the results of the `member` attribute. I misunderstood. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

The query filter only affects the objects returned, not the values of the attributes returned for that object. So the filter of `(CN=GON)` means, "I want to find a group with the `cn` is `GON`" and the `attr` value tells it which attributes to return. LDAP does not provide a way to modify how those attributes are returned.

You can filter them after the search is complete. Loop through each value and remove the ones you don't want.

Another way to find all users in one specific OU who are a member of a group is to look at the `memberOf` attribute. This will work in Active Directory, but I'm not sure about OpenLDAP (I think `memberOf` has to be configured to work, but I'm not sure - I've never actually used OpenLDAP).

So in AD, you can make a query like this:

```
basedn = "OU=Users,DC=com"
filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(memberOf=CN=GON,OU=App,OU=Groups,DC=com))"
attr = ["distinguishedName"]
scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE

result = l.search_s(basdn, scope, filter, attr)
```

This works well in AD domains where there is only one domain in the forest. But in multi-domain forests, [beware of `memberOf`](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html#beware-of-memberof).